a syntax error in the file name, folder name, or volume label
@echo off
cd {C\Users\misha\Desktop\performance_monitor}
"{C\Users\misha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\pip}" app.py
pause
a syntax error in the file name, folder name, or volume label.
I removed the colons on the way did not help

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
